# Reorder Backbone collection in initialize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to find a way to reorganize a Backbone collection in the `initialize` function of a view. In my collection I have models that have attributes like:

```
id: ...,
name: ...,
sort: 2,
parent: 45
```

The `parent` property is what I am interested in. I would like to move all models that have a `parent` id of 45 to the beginning of a collection. There may be 200 models and maybe 30 have a parent of 45, 15 have a parent of 50, etc... I would like to the keep the chunk that I move in the same order it was in before (it's ordered by the `sort` property to begin with, I would like to keep it in that original order).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use underscore's [groupBy](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#groupBy)

```
var mySorted = _.groupBy(collection.models, function (model) {
  return model.get('parent') === 45 ? 'top' : 'rest' ;
});
```

Then `mysorted.top` contains all the ones with parent 45. `mySorted.rest` obviously contains the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Define a new [comparator](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator) on your class.  This will keep your collection in any order you wish.